# when event's due date over send email to a fixed user's email (xyz@abc.com)

Tags: apex, batch

I want to send email to a fixed user's email address let say `(abc@xyz.com (mailto:abc@xyz.com))` when events due date over and description is not filled.
I wrote batch but it send to email event owner not specific user. could you please help me to find out how can I put hard coated email address in batch.
below is my batch please have a look and let me know if any changes are required.

Comment: Add your code. i think you forget to add.

Comment: Try with Trigger and EmailMessaging API.

Comment: @TusharSharma you can see their code over here on the developer forums ;)
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MJauIAG

Answer (score 1):

When you are sending an e-mail from apex code.. make sure you explicitly set the toEmailAddress... such as

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> msgs = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

// KEY LINE:
msg.setToAddress('abc@xyz.com');

// Set other message details
// eg. msg.setTemplateID(template.Id); 
// eg. msg.setWhatId(custom_object.Id);

msgs.add(msg);
Messaging.sendEmail(msgs,false);
```

That will explicitly send the e-mail to the given hard coded address.

I believe other advise has included using a custom setting or custom label to store a contextual email address in a declarative feature, so you don't have to alter apex to change this e-mail address if it ever moves.